# R writting in file "" for null or na value

Tags: r, null, na

I am trying to write a dataframe in a file with the write.table function
I have to fallow a particular format where empty value are represented by "" in the file

I edited my dataframe with "", NA and NULL values prior to using write.table without much success. With NULL I get "NULL", with NA and "" I get nothing in the file

Comment: Try this: `DF[is.na(DF)]<-''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `na` parameter when using write.table. As per it's description: **na**:*the string to use for missing value in data*

```
write.table(df, na='""')
```

Comment: Thank I was using na="" in the function parameter but it was not working because na="" means NA to the function, instead I add two simple quote ' around "" (na = '""') and now it is working

Comment: @user1946989 I though you wanted the empty-string as your `NA` See if the change is what you did. Alternatively you can also use `na="\"\""`